# How to use a C# Object Array as a Property

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, object

I can use this snippet:

```
public object Obj
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Like this:

```
public fubar()
{
    ...
    Obj = SomeObject;
}
```

But cannot seem to use this snippet:

```
public object[] ObjectAsArray
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Like this or any other way I have tried so far:

```
public fubar()
{
    ...
    Obj[n] = SomeObject;
    //or 
    var x = Obj[0] as SomeObject;
    //or other ways...
}
```

I seem to be missing something here.

Can somebody give a simple example of the correct declaration of a C# property that is of type `object[]` and consumption thereof?

Comment: If the existing answers don't help, please say what's going wrong, and provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to set `Obj[n]` before `Obj` itself is initialized... so, I imagine you're getting a null-reference exception. You need to perform an assignment, like so:

```
Obj = new Object[];
```

... and in context:

```
public fubar()
{

  Obj = new Object[13]{}; // where 13 is the number of elements
  Obj[n] = SomeObject;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you change it from `Obj` to `ObjectAsArray` it should compile. You'll still need to actually *create* the array though:

```
ObjectAsArray = new object[10];
ObjectAsArray[5] = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a private backing field for the object[] property and initialize it - either directly or in the getter.

```
object[] _objectsAsArray = new object[10];
```

OR

```
public object[] ObjectAsArray   
{       
     get 
     { 
         if(_objectsAsArray == null)
             _objectsAsArray = new object[10];
         return _objectsAsArray;
     }
     set
     {
        _objectsAsArray = value;   
     } 
}
```

The complier is creating a private backing field anyhow so why not be explicit about it.  Also, auto-implemented properties have some drawbacks (serialization, threading, etc).  Doing it the "old-fashioned" way also gives you a nice place to actually create the array.  Of course if you don't need to worry these issues - go ahead and use the auto-implemented property.